# Why does setting width in a CSS class attached to my labels not change their width?

Tags: html, css

I've got this html:

```
<label class="fixedwidthlbl" for="city">City</label>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city">
<br/>
<label class="fixedwidthlbl" for="state">State</label>
<input type="text" name="state" id="state">
<br/>
<label class="fixedwidthlbl" for="yearin">Year Arrived</label>
<input type="text" name="yearin" id="yearin">
<br/>
<label class="fixedwidthlbl" for="yearout">Year Departed</label>
<input type="text" name="yearout" id="yearout">
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="insertdocument" id="insertdocument" value="Add Place Lived">
```

...and this CSS:

```
.fixedwidthlbl {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 2 px;  
}
```

Yet the "fixedwidthlbl" class is having no effect on my labels.

I've got a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/u54xz3d3/).

What is wrong with my HTML and/or CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

label are inline elements. To give them a width you will need to give them `display: inline-block;`

```
.fixedwidthlbl {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 2px;   
    display: inline-block;
}
```